# Batch: create folders based on first part filename; copy files into that folder

Tags: file, batch-file, copy, directory

I have a folder with millions of small images. I want to put the first 12.288 files in one folder then the next 12.288 files in another folder and so on... always according to the first part of the filename. The files are named like this:

```
GRID_00000_01

GRID_00000_02
```

till

```
GRID_00000_12288
```

and then the next group of files:

```
GRID_00001_01
```

till

```
GRID_00001_12288
```

This goes on till `GRID_12288_12288`

I would like that the batch creates a folder `GRID_00000` for all the files that are starting with that filename and then put all the files inside. Then it has to do the same with the next group of files and so on.  I don't know if I make myself clear because I really don't know a lot about programming.

My system is windows 8.1

The source-directory is called:

```
D:\photoshop\test\grid_04\droplet\Bilder
```

The destination-directory is called:

```
D:\photoshop\test\grid_04\droplet\geordnet
```

I have found this on the internet:

```
    @echo off

    for /f %%a in ('dir /a-d /b') do (
      if not "%%~dpnxa"=="%~dpnx0" call :func "%%~a"
    )

    goto :EOF

    :func
    set file=%~1
    set dir=%file:~0,10%
    md "T%dir%" 2>nul

move "%file%" "T%dir%" 
goto :EOF
```

It doesn't specify the destination directory. But actually it isn't necessary. It's also good if the folders are created within the original folder.

Comment: This is more of a photoshop question than a programming question.

Comment: I didn't find a solution in photoshop. That's why I thought to arrange the files afterwards.

Comment: @sjoy sorry, the post abobe was meant for Casey Rule.

Comment: @sjoy I found something on the internet and first I thought it would be the sollution (I pasted it in my original post). I tried it with a folder with lesser files and it worked, but with the original folder it doesen't.

Comment: Hi. You don't want to post code from answers in your question. Just leave a comment at end of the answer like you did. You can "rollback" the edit where you added my code in your question. **Oh, but I do see problem. In new code, be sure to change both the dest and src paths at the top.**

Comment: @sjoy OK, but I don't understand what you mean with "rollback".

Comment: @sjoy I did. And it creates one folder that is called GRID_00000. So I don't think that this is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"

FOR /f "tokens=1,2,*delims=_" %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\grid_*_*" ') DO (
 ECHO(MD "%destdir%\%%a_%%b" 2>nul
 ECHO(MOVE "%sourcedir%\%%a_%%b_%%c" "%destdir%\%%a_%%b\%%a_%%b_%%c"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

The required MD commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(MD` to `MD` to actually create the directories. The `2>nul` suppresses error messages (eg. when the directory already exists)

The required MOVE commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(MOVE` to `MOVE` to actually move the files.  Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file moved`)

Comment: Yes, move of course, sigh. Afraid I'm going to have to borrow that from  you.